# Collectionview Cell Delegate method not called on scrollToItemAtIndexPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

I use `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` in the `viewDidLayoutSubviews` part of my controller to allow me to scroll a user to a specific cell.

My cells are supposed to make network calls for their params when they are loaded as part of the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

The issue is that putting a print statement in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` it appears it's never called? What's the cause of the conflict here and the solution to make it work? Code as follows:

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    CDCChannelCollectionView *scrollView;

    if (self.view == [self mixMonitorView]) {
        scrollView = [[self mixMonitorView] scrollView];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:0 inSection: self.selectedChanIndex];
        [scrollView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally animated:YES];
    }
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CDCChannelStrip *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (self.view == self.mixMonitorView) {
        NSInteger chanInt = indexPath.section;
        NSNumber *chanNum = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:chanInt];
        NSNumber *chanNameNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:chanInt + 1];
        NSString *chanName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"CH %@", chanNameNumber];
        cell.channelNumber = chanInt;
        cell.channelName.text = chanName;
        [self getParameters:(chanNum)];
        [self.mixMonitorView setChannelsStripToType:(cell)];
        cell.clipsToBounds = YES;
        return cell;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to scroll to selected index right ?

Comment: yes the scrolling isnt the issue, it works fine, its the fact it doesnt call the cells delegate method correctly after

Comment: Yes bcus you are doing wrong call do like this `NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:self.selectedChanIndex inSection:0];`

Comment: the collectionview is made from sections not items, your code does nothing

Comment: your code should throw error in cellforItemIndexpath , do you have any more code in that ??

Comment: Why not from item ? its working with items in sections what you want here jump to particular section or jump to any cell item ? please provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Datasource method will call on reloading the collection view.

Try below

```
[yourCollectionViewName reloadData];
```

Comment: After scrolling to a particular index, you must have call datasource method. Have you try this?

Comment: well no as it should call the methods when it creates the reusable cell as it does when i scroll manually

Answer (score 0):

`scrollToItemAtIndexPath` will not call datasource methods unless it is scrolling to a `collectionViewCell` which is not visible before scrolling. You need to call `reloadData` if it is scrolling to an already visible cell

Comment: its scrolling to a non visible cell, horizontally..so it should call